# Data replication from MS SQL to Salesforce

Tags: data-export, database

I'm trying to setup our MSSQL server to "replicate" new insert/updates to Salesforce, but it appears that there is no official way to do it via Salesforce. Is there a recommended way?

Background: I'm trying to set up realtime or near realtime update/inserts of our sales data to replicate to Salesforce database so our sales in the field can have the latest information on sales that are done

I have tried various appexchange apps, and so far Jitterbit seems to be the one that will get the job done(though I haven't been able to get it going). However my manager kept on mentioning to me that there must be a way to do database to database replication. Is this possible at all with Salesforce? (please tell me if I'm misunderstanding what database to database replication means -> no app in middle?)

Thank you.

Comment: There are various data integration vendors (e.g. Informatica) that should be looked at (and they'll provide mapping support from dissimilar schemas). You are correct that this is not native OOB SFDC

Comment: There are so many products in the App Exchange which support Replication API like informatica, DBAmp, Relational Junction. You can Build your own replication mechanism using the Replication API or tools like Talend, JitterBit Data loader.

Comment: "However my manager kept on mentioning to me that there must be a way to do database to database replication" -- I love this...assert something and it must be true.  Yes, database replication is possible but it is not native OOB SFDC - you need to use a third party product such as suggested here. SFDC supports OOB SFDC<->SFDC only called `Salesforce to Salesforce`

Answer (score 2):

Relational Junction has a product that does exactly what you describe, and are an AppExchange partner.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked through Relational Junction yesterday and spoke to a rep, it is a really good software. the only problem was that it cost way too much for what my needs are at the moment, definitely worth considering if my needs grow though

Answer (score -1):

So I've tried various method and apps and it looks like this is the best choice if all you want to do is to "upsert" certain data from your local database to Salesforce database

Jitterbit Data Loader for Salesforce
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZoVEAU

It says free on app exchange, allows Queries/Upserts/Insert/Update/Delete/Bulk Processes and has the ability to sechedule jobs in frequencies up to seconds, I have yet to test out the reliability though

I will mark this as the answer for now, if anyone else have a better solution please post it and I will change it

Thanks,

Comment: Nataku: I have mentioned the same in my above answer
There are so many products in the App Exchange which support Replication API like informatica, DBAmp, Relational Junction. You can Build your own replication mechanism using the Replication API or tools like Talend, JitterBit Data loader.

Comment: good god, I forgot I got it from your comment, you want to reply as answer and I'll mark that as answer instead? (honest mistake)

Comment: we were just trying to help you, so if you think it helps, you will have to give an upvote. That is how this forum works :)

Comment: Didn't know you could up vote comments, thanks :)